# How can helm-find-files be adapted to include previously open files, projects etc?

Tags: helm, find-file

After doing some more search concerning [Does the recent files in emacs display files opened in previous sessions?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34042) I realize that `C-x C-f` is bound in my config to `helm-find-files`.
How can helm-find-files be configured to include previously open files, previous projects' directories etc in the original search list, followed by files from general disk searches? `C-c p F` is mapped to `projectile-find-file-in-known-projects` which shows files in previous projects.

But as `C-x C-f` is the default keys for opening a file I want it to combine previously used files, project directories  then the general file system in the search.